# MongoDB: No write concern mode named 'majority a' found in replica set configuration

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am working through a traversy media tutorial and I've come across an error (in the title) that I'm not familiar with. I've been trying to learn about this but I'm still stumped as to why its appearing and where its coming from. Furthermore, I havent found any direct matches for this issue.

Here is the code in question, the catch at the bottom is returning the error.message.

edit: its also worth noting that I am able to successfuly add users to my database. So, it runs through the `try` block but *also* the `catch` ... so thats a big confusing. The only response I am getting on postman is the server error 500 message from the `catch` block.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require('gravatar');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const User = require('../../models/User');

// @route   GET api/users
// @desc    Test route
// @access  Public
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check(
      'password',
      'Please enter a password with 6 or more characters'
    ).isLength({ min: 6 }),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });
      
      // see if user exists
      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: [{ msg: 'User already exists' }],
        });
      }

      // get users gravatar
      const avatar = gravatar.url(email, {
        s: '200',
        r: 'pg',
        d: 'mm',
      });

      user = new User({
        name,
        email,
        avatar,
        password,
      });

      // encrypt password
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

      await user.save();

      // return jsonwebtoken
      return res.send('User registered');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

The User schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

connection configuration:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Comment: Please add the connection configuration.
'majorty a' is really not a legal write concern. It could be 'majority'.

Comment: @noam its been updated

Comment: @noam i looked at the connection string from mongodb and at some point i fat-fingered `majority a` at the end of the string.

Comment: Glad your problem is solved :)